# groovy get the name of the parent script

Tags: groovy, parent

We have the following situation:
we have two groovy scripts, script1.groovy and script2.groovy,
script1.groovy is executing script2.groovy.

is there any method that i can call inside script2.groovy in order to find out who what script called script2.groovy ?

Comment: Can you provide more information e.g. how do you load `script2.groovy` from `script1.groovy` file?

Comment: @Library("some-library-name") --- and this contains script2.groovy and other scripts.
and inside script1.groovy we have something like:
script1(param1, param2, param3)

Comment: are you inside jenkins pipeline? if yes - please modify the question and add corresponding tags. in any case the question `who calls me` in java (groovy) could be resolved through stacktrace. Just get it through `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` and try to find in the returned array of `StackTraceElement`s the item with  `it.getFileName().endsWith('.groovy')`.